# Access table name in Postgres ddl_command_start event trigger

Tags: postgresql, event-triggers

I'd like to write a Postgres event trigger to capture the name and schema of a table *before* it is created, using `ddl_command_start`. However, it seems like this is only available from `pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()`, which can only be called at `ddl_command_end`.

Is there any way to get the table name at `ddl_command_start` ?

Comment: The function is not available on `dll_command_start` as the object does not exist yet. What's the reason that you cannot use `ddl_command_end`?

Comment: @klin you can easily argue that it's a bad idea, but I ended up writing the trigger in C (where the names are indeed available), see https://github.com/dbaston/pg_implicit_schema

Comment: I don't think it's a bad idea. It may be useful in the described case. And you need a C function indeed.